# Spring 5 Web Reactive - Clarification about DTO response body conversion

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webflux

According to the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#web-reactive-http-body):

> The response body can be one of the following:
>
> - Account — serialize without blocking the given Account; implies a synchronous, non-blocking controller method.

How come a synchronous controller method can be non-blocking? It sounds like a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a synchronous, non-blocking controller method:

```
@GetMapping("/sample/account")
public Account sample() {
  return new Account("codependent");
}
```

It's synchronous because it does not return a type that signals a deferred result (like `Mono` or `Flux`). It's non-blocking because no blocking operation is performed (I/O, waiting on a shared resource, etc).

You could wrap it with a `Mono` like `Mono.just(new Account("codependent"))`, but you'd just pay the cost of that async type for no reason.

Comment: So this should only be used when the controller method doesn't do anything blocking. The point is that I don't see many situations when it would apply, I mean: if we do something async, we will have a Mono, if we do something blocking, it won't be serialized without blocking...BTW, thanks for answering.